# Is it possible to control the EV3 brick with a GUI on PC? If so hows the best way to go about it

Tags: ev3, remote-control, python

I've been interested in controlling a machine remotely through a GUI and I am stuck in between picking Python or Java to do this project in but I also think the way I'm going about this would be all wrong.

The idea would work something like this:

1. Connect via Bluetooth
2. Create a simple GUI with buttons corresponding to the device attached (like a motor)
3. When a button is pressed then the device would activate

However I'm not sure if this would work?

Comment: If it doesn't **have** to be an EV3 brick, I would think WeDo would be what you're looking for (remotely, but perhaps not wirelessly). But WeDo has been replaced by Spike, and I don't know enough about it to say if it does what you want.

Comment: This is possible with the powered up app and powered up motors and hubs (either the technic hub or city hub, not spike, robotic inventor or EV3). Although I've heard that the environment is not intuitive and has a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

For mobile devices, there is an official LEGO app called *LEGO® MINDSTORMS® Commander* that can do this ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.mindstorms.robotcommander&gl=US), [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lego-mindstorms-commander/id681786521), [Fire](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IN3Z6C2), [Windows](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/lego%C2%AE-mindstorms%C2%AE-commander/XPDLPLDBMT8990)).

If you want to write your own app, you will need to use the [EV3 communication protocol](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/communication.html).